# Unable to execute stored procedure on Cosmos DB from Azure Portal

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm unable to execute any stored procedure that, I create for Cosmos DB on the Azure Portal. The 'Save and Execute' button is always grayed out in the script explorer.

[Unable to click on the 'Save and Execute' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1jBQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the collection partitioned? The portal currently does not support executing stored procedures on partitioned collections. You can still use the SDK to execute the stored procedure, however. The portal will support this functionality in the near future.

Comment: Yes, the collection is partitioned. Is there no quicker alternative to execute the stored procedure. I'm trying to get the unique values from the collection since, 'DISTINCT' and 'GROUP BY' is not available as of now.